# Google Deep Learning Platform unable to use tensorflow 2.3

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-dl-platform

I previously made a Deep Learning instance with Tensorflow 2.3 yesterday but encountered some issues getting the GPU to work so I tried deleting and creating a new Deep Learning instance but now I am unable to use version 2.3

It was available a few days ago but now it is not. I need to use this version as some of the features I am using are unavailable in version 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to manually upgrade the version of tensorflow using:

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow==2.3.0
```